# how to center an image horizontal and vertical inside an edit text in android xml

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext, android-drawable

[Something like this please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haRvD.png)

I'm new to android, and I am trying to center the image and hint both vertical and horizontal. If anyone can help, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: you cant put an image inside an EditText for this you have to use a FrameLayout. Also please add your working...

Answer (score 0):

You can't put ImageView inside of an EditText. 
You can, instead, put EditView and TextView inside RelativeLayout and center them, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"          
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is some edit text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since we put EditText width and height to match RelativeLayout, it would appear as if the ImageView is inside of an EditText.

If you want to put text under image just add this line to TextView: android:layout_below="@+id/my_image_view".